# Grabbing a URL out of an NSString using regex

Tags: html, regex, string, url, xml-parsing

I have a string that I have parsed from XML using Google's GDataXML parser, and now I need to get the string narrowed down a little bit more. THe contents of the string currently looks like this:

```
<Side><Image source='http://website.stuff.edu/img/user'/></Side>
```

I can't change the way the xml is coming, so this is the string I have to parse. I have tried this regex:

```
http:(.*?)'
```

But it grabs the ending quote of the url which I don't want, I just need to grab from http to the end of the url...

I know this is like stupidly easy, but I am not sure of the syntax. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
http://([^']+)
```

EDIT #1:

Basically, `[^']+` is "anything other than single quote 1 or more times"